# One character per line in mod election

Tags: bug, election, responsive-design, election-page

On every single page for elections ([example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/2?tab=nomination)), I see the first response written one character or word per line, with the name box of the author skewed off to the left:

[image: nomination: one or two words per line]

[image: comment on nomination: one character per line]

[image: primary: one character per line]

[image: election: one character per line]

While this is fixed by zooming out (even though zoom’s not technically supported *GASP*) or going into landscape mode, I still think this needs to be fixed. Neither one of those options will be particularly obvious to everyone and it’s impossible to read otherwise.

I think this is caused by the tabs being next to the content.

(Some other things that seem problematic is that all the scores in the primary are 0 and the buttons are weirdly styled/nigh unreadable, with the latter being a well known problem with iPhone/Safari.)

Comment: It looks fine on my Pixel 3a with Android 10 and Chrome. I'm not saying it is not an issue, just that it is fine on a different device.